# Un-commenting xml block using sed command

Tags: xml, bash, sed

I have xml file which has many elements commented. From all of these elements, I want to uncomment one element using sed command.

I have xml file as:

```
<!-- This is the sample xml
    which holds the data of the students -->
<Students>
    <!-- <student>
        <name>john</>
        <id>123</id>
    </student> -->
    <student>
        <name>mike</name>
        <id>234</id>
    </student>
    <!-- <student>
        <name>NewName</name>
        <id>NewID</id>
    </student> -->
</Students>
```

In the above xml file, I want uncomment the last xml block, so my file will look like

```
<!-- This is the sample xml
    which holds the data of the students -->
<Students>
    <!-- <student>
        <name>john</>
        <id>123</id>
    </student> -->
    <student>
        <name>mike</name>
        <id>234</id>
    </student>
    <student>
        <name>NewName</name>
        <id>NewID</id>
    </student> 
</Students>
```

I gone through the sed command, but didn't get how can delete just `<!--` and `-->` from last block. Is it possible to uncomment xml block with `<name>` as `NewName` ? I didn't find any thing apart from deleting whole line.

EDIT: I can have many xml elements other than `<name>` and `<id>` like `<address>, <city>, <class>,<marks>`.

Comment: In your input only the first `student` is surrounded by a comment. The third isn't. In fact, the input is not valid XML.

Comment: I have updated the question. by mistaken I typed wrong here. But the problem exists still

Comment: I doubt that what you want to do is possible. Parsing XML is hard.

Comment: So is there any other way using awk or anything? But I want use shell script only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r '/<Students>/,/<\/Students>/{/<Students>/{h;d};H;/<\/Students>/!d;g;s/(.*)<!-- (.*) -->(.*)/\1\2\3/}' file
```

This stores the `Students` data in the hold space then uses greed to find the last occurence of `<!--` and `-->` and removes them before printing the data.

Comment: Here I want to remove last student element only which has <name> as NewName. Students is parent tag and student is child element here. So I am confused with your command in pattern matching

Comment: @Optimus this stores multiple lines and then removes the last start/end comment tags.

Comment: Thanks @potong, would you please tell me why \1\2\3 is required?

Comment: @Optimus these are [back references](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Regular-Expressions).

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `sed`. Use [`xsltproc`](http://xmlsoft.org/XSLT/xsltproc.html).

```
<!-- uncomment.xsl -->
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <!-- this copies every input node unchanged -->
  <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- this uncomments every comment that starts with a `<` -->
  <xsl:template match="comment()[substring(normalize-space(), 1, 1) = '&lt;']">
    <xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="yes" />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

on the command line:

```
xsltproc -o output.xml uncomment.xsl input.xml
```

If it works correctly, you get this for your input XML:

```
<!-- This is the sample xml
    which holds the data of the students -->
<Students>
    <student>
        <name>john</name>
        <id>123</id>
    </student>
    <student>
        <name>mike</name>
        <id>234</id>
    </student>
    <student>
        <name>NewName</name>
        <id>NewID</id>
    </student>
</Students>
```